# Searching for an example of a theorem wich is "easy" to prove in a classical way but way more difficult in the setting of non-standard analysis.

Tags: soft-question, nonstandard-analysis

I´m learning some non-standard analysis. Quite some basic properties and theorems are "easier" to prove in the setting of non-standard analysis. But I´m searching for the converse, does anyone know some examples of results which are "more difficult" (the structure of the proof is more advanced, the proof is lengthier,...) to prove using non-standard analysis?

Many thanks!

Comment: Defining the hyper-real field.

Comment: @Doug M You don't need a hyper-real field. Have you heard of Nelson's internal set theory?

Comment: @Doug I don't follow. How is a definition a theorem? Or are you saying that defining a (not *the*) hyper-real field is harder using non-standard analysis?

Comment: There are several results establishing in precise ways how the non-standard setting simplifies arguments. On the other hand, one could argue the question is ill-posed, since the non-standard setting gives you more machinery, it does not remove the old one, so it is impossible for proofs to get harder.

Comment: I think it's reasonable to ask for cases where the new machinery simply doesn't help, though.

Answer (score 1):

The wording of this question suggests a common misconception that involves interpreting the term "non-standard" in the name of this field in its generic meaning.  For this reason it is preferable to refer to the field as "Robinson's framework for analysis with infinitesimals", "infinitesimal analysis", or something along those lines.  The point is that Robinson's framework is a conservative extension of the classical one and as such *incorporates all of the techniques available in the "classical" setting you referred to.  In other words, Robinson's framework is *part* of the classical framework but provides *new tools* that can be used fruitfully where the old tools become too awkward.  Thus by definition it is *impossible* to give "properties or theorems" that are harder to prove in Robinson's framework than in the "classical" framework as you put it.